# asp.net access database not updating

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, ms-access, datasource

I am trying to update values in my access database, however it does not work in some cases.

The code :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/Database1.mdb" 
        DeleteCommand="UPDATE DT_Person SET Deleted = NOW() WHERE (Person_Ref = ?)" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [DT_Person] ([Person_Ref], [Created], [Updated], [Deleted],     [Person_Name], [Person_No]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [DT_Person]" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE DT_Person SET Updated = NOW(), Person_Name = ?, Person_No = ? WHERE (Person_Ref = ?)">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Person_Ref" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Created" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Updated" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Deleted" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Person_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Person_No" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Person_Ref" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Person_Ref" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Created" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Updated" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Deleted" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Person_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Person_No" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" 
        BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
        DataKeyNames="Person_Ref" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
        <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" 
                ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Person_Ref" HeaderText="Person_Ref" 
                InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Person_Ref" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Created" HeaderText="Created" 
                SortExpression="Created" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Updated" HeaderText="Updated" 
                SortExpression="Updated" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Deleted" HeaderText="Deleted" 
                SortExpression="Deleted" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Person_Name" HeaderText="Person_Name" 
                SortExpression="Person_Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Person_No" HeaderText="Person_No" 
                SortExpression="Person_No" />
        </Columns>
```

As you can see, the delete command

```
(DeleteCommand="UPDATE DT_Person SET Deleted = NOW() WHERE (Person_Ref = ?)" )
```

is really an update statement and this works fine . However the actual update statement does not work on the web page. The weird thing is, if you test the query in the 'query builder' it works fine.

Really need some help here.

TIA

P.S. Im using Visual Studio 2008 and using the data source builder each time

Comment: I just tested that and it works for me. What error messages are you getting? Have you got the right permissions on the Access file and folder?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 (if that's what you're using) has been known to make a copy of Access databases down in the Debug files and use the copy for all data changes.  You might want to check that the database you are actually accessing is the copy you think it is.

Do a search for files with the same name across your whole development machine.  You might be surprised what turns up.